# Should an activity without connection to a repository have a ViewModel?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

I am trying to understand MVVM on Android.

Assuming I have this simple application: (behaviour like Google contact app)

- ListActivity: List of contacts from server
- DetailActivity: detail screen of one contact (opened by click on list item)

---

For this list it is pretty clear how to implement mvvm pattern:

- Activity is observing live data from view model and is updating recycler view
- ViewModel: getAllContacts from repository
- Repository: getAllContacts from server/DB/etc..

---

If the user clicks now on a contact in the list Detail screen will open:
ListActivity does putExtra(“CONTACT”, chosenContact) and is starting detailActivity

DetailActivity is getting this ContactObject and is creating this view:

- show image
- show name
- create contact options (call, sms, video)

As you can see in my example DetailScreen is not communicating with repository. 
It has already received all needed data from intent.

---

**Questions:**

1. Should you create a view model for this detailActivity?
2. If yes, what are the tasks of this view model if there is no connection to a repository needed?
3. In google contacts app I have the options to delete a contact and to add contact to favorites. These should be done in a viewModel and this ViewModel needs a connection to a repository? Tasks of DetailActivity like call, send message, video call or share contact need context so as far as I understand MVVM they should be done in Activity class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should you create a view model for this detailActivity?

In your case there is no need for it.

> If yes, what are the tasks of this view model if there is no connection to a repository needed?

ViewModel helps a lot keeping state of an activity/fragment. If you had a spinner, or a checkbox, or any other field that could change, like a description text field inserted by the user, viewmodel would help keep the data even when the user rotates the phone.

> In google contacts app I have the options to delete a contact and to add contact to favorites. These should be done in a viewModel and this ViewModel needs a connection to a repository?

Yes, your UI would call a fun in your viewmodel that would send to the repository, etc.

> Tasks of DetailActivity like call, send message, video call or share contact need context so as far as I understand MVVM they should be done in Activity class?

Exactly, there is no need to use the viewmodel to send an intent to share a contact with another app, for instance.